# Difficulty transferring prawn pdf image to frontend

Tags: rmagick, prawn

I am streaming a prawn PDF to the frontend of my application, but it shows the image as 100% black.  The image is a gif file that I convert to png using rmagick.  If I save the pdf file on the backend, it looks correct. I have tried other png files instead, and they render properly.  What aspects of the png file could cause it to work fine on the backend, but show up as a black rectangle on the frontend?

Backend code:

```
png_blobs = []
      gif_blobs.each do |gif_blob|
        gif = ImageList.new
        # gif_blob is streamed from UPS' API
        gif = gif.from_blob(Base64.decode64(gif_blob))
        gif.crop!(0, 0, 1202, 800) # get rid of whitespace that comes with UPS label
        gif.rotate!(-90.0)
        gif.format = 'png'
        gif.profile!("8bim",nil)
        blob = gif.to_blob
        png_blobs.push(StringIO.open(blob)) # I have tried using the blob and the file
        gif.write('/tmp/myfile.png'){ |options| options.quality = 50 }
        # png_blobs.push('/tmp/myfile.png')
      end

Prawn::Document.new(page_size: [386, 578], margin: 0) do |pdf|
        pdf.define_grid(columns: 38, rows: 57, gutter: 0)
        png_blobs.each_with_index do |gif_png_blob, idx|
          pdf.grid([0, 0], [57, 38]).bounding_box do
            pdf.image gif_png_blob, scale: 0.2
            # Same problem with this attempt below, except it turns 100% gray due to transparency
            # pdf.transparent(0.5) do
            #   pdf.image '/tmp/myfile.png', width: 386, scale: 0.48
            # end
            # This actually works, but it is a completely different png file
            pdf.image Rails.root.join('app/assets', 'images', 'ups_barcode.png'), scale: 0.2
          end
          pdf.start_new_page if idx < png_blobs.length - 1
        end

        pdf.render_file('/tmp/myfile.pdf') # This looks good
        # this shows a black rectangle on the frontend
        body['ShipmentResponse']['ShipmentResults']['PackageResults']['ShippingLabel'] = Base64.encode64(pdf.render)
end
```

Comment: @KJ I appreciate your idea!! I tried removing the alpha, and the same problem. I also tried converting to jpg and had the same problem except the page was all white...any ideas? (Again, the file looks fine on my local rails server, just not when I download the pdf on the frontend using JavaScript (Vue3))

Comment: @KJ Thank you. This got me somewhere!  If I use `send_data`, I can now get it to work, but `render` is not working given a desire to send back some other JSON data to accompany the pdf.  Again, other images/pdfs seem to work.  Are you aware why this may not work or if there is some flag to make render work?  I can rework all the code, but would prefer not to...

Answer (score 0):

Using `send_data` as opposed to `render` (along with other json) in rails seemed to fix this problem.  That said, all of my other images and pdfs that didn't use ImageMagick were fine in the `render` function.